# How to get the selected value in a dropbox generated by Data Contract?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I am trying to get the selected value of a dropdown box generated by Data Contract.

my code is something like this:

Code in Data Contract

```
public EDTenum parmSource(EDTenum _source = source)
{
    source = _source;

   return source;
}
```

the dropdown data are ENUM.

I am not sure but I declared the parmSource in my Data Provider like so:

```
EDTenum source;
contract = this.parmDataContract();
source = contract.parmSource();
```

So source is where the value of the dropdown box stored. (I don't know if this is correct as well)

Really just want to get the value selected in the dropdown created from the Data Contract.

Comment: Looks ok, Do you have any errors in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you call `contract = this.getDataContractObject()` to get your contract in a later context.

Also, do you decorate your contract and its members correctly with attributes?  See here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg844225.aspx